# How to keep rows with NULL values that don't fulfill the condition in the WHERE clause after LEFT JOIN-ing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables:

```
person
| Id | Name |
| ---| -----| 
| 1  | Bob  | 
| 2  | Mary | 

sales
| SalesID  | PersonID| Year | Amount |
| -------  | ------- | ---- | ------ |
| 1        | 1       | 2010 | 100    |
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN sales on person.ID = sales.PersonID WHERE sales.Year = 2010 GROUP BY person.ID
```

What I get:

```
 | Id | Name | SalesID  | PersonID| Year | Amount |
 | ---| -----| -------  | ------- | ---- | ------ |
 | 1  | Bob  | 1        | 1       | 2010 | 100    |
```

What I want:

```
| Id | Name | SalesID  | PersonID| Year | Amount |
| ---| -----| -------  | ------- | ---- | ------ |
| 1  | Bob  | 1        | 1       | 2010 | 100    |
| 2  | Mary | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
```

I want to see the amount for every person for a specific year. If a person didn't sell anything in that year (no sales have that persons ID), I still want it included in the result.

Comment: It's not the JOIN or GROUP that remove Mary's row. It's the WHERE clause.

Comment: I realized that. I just couldn't figure a way to include Mary's row while keeping the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to let `sales.Year = 2010` be  `on` clause condition instead of `where`
clause.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
   Id INT,
   Name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1,'Bob'); 
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2,'Mary');

CREATE TABLE sales(
   SalesID INT,
   PersonID INT,
     Year INT,
   Amount INT
);


INSERT INTO sales VALUES (1,1 ,2010,100 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person 
LEFT JOIN sales on person.ID = sales.PersonID and sales.Year = 2010
GROUP BY person.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26d5a/1/0)**:

```
| Id | Name | SalesID | PersonID |   Year | Amount |
|----|------|---------|----------|--------|--------|
|  1 |  Bob |       1 |        1 |   2010 |    100 |
|  2 | Mary |  (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

**Note**

If you are doing an outer`JOIN`, add `WHERE` conditions to `ON` clause for tables. This is a must because adding a `WHERE` clause that will only get `sales.Year = 2010` row.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Виктор No problem gald to help :)